# Names for levels of calculus

Tags: calculus

Differentiation can be said to take an expression to a higher order derivative. It seems that different variables inhabit different 'levels' of calculus, some from different areas seem analogous to each other in a way that I am searching for a word for. For example between electrical and mechanical:

1) Charge and displacement
2) Current and velocity
3) Potential difference and force

What is the name for the numbers on the left of the list: 'order', 'level'? I haven't found the subject addressed directly anywhere.

Comment: I _think_ the answer to your question is in the physics of your examples, not the mathematics. It's the _units_ of those quantities that matter. The units of $dy/dx$ are always (units of $y$)/(units of $x$). Perhaps ask at physics stackexchange.

Comment: Are you asking for the mechanical analogues of electrical components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we deal with derivatives and others releted topic as for example **[differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#General_definition)** or Taylor's expansion we use the term "**[order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Higher_derivatives)**".

Comment: Thanks!
________